# Centering tildes on new lines in equation arrays

Tags: equations, tilde

I have been using LaTex since a few weeks, and I have a lot of equations in my text. Up until now everything was perfectly doable, but now I am looking for a way to decrease the spacing between the following formulas and the tildes (~ characters) and I just can't find the right explanation. I think the following code is horrible, but it is the best example I can think of that shows my intentions.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{det}\begin{bmatrix}
    w-\lambda & x\\
    y &z-\lambda
    \end{bmatrix}=0
\end{eqnarray*}\begin{eqnarray*}\sim\end{eqnarray*}\begin{eqnarray*}
(w-\lambda)(z-\lambda)-yx=0
\end{eqnarray*}\begin{eqnarray*}\sim\end{eqnarray*}\begin{eqnarray*}
\lambda ^2-(w+z)\lambda +(wz-yx)=0
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Replacing the `\end{eqnarray*}\begin{eqnarray*}` with `\\ \sim \\` results in the distance being correct, but the tildes not being in the middle of the surrounding equations. Trying to replace `\end{eqnarray*}\begin{eqnarray*}` with something like `\\ \text{\begin{center} $\sim$ \end{center}}\\` results in an error message. Could someone please help me with this?

NB:Alignment in = characters is permitted but not requested as long as all equations are around the center of the page.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) forget you ever heard of `eqnarray` it is very broken, (3) use `align*` (you are already using `amsmath`) and write all the lines in one `align*` instead of all those `eqnarray*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is better with `equation*` and `array`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c}
\mathrm{det}\begin{bmatrix}
    w-\lambda & x\\
    y &z-\lambda
    \end{bmatrix}=0 \\
\sim \\
(w-\lambda)(z-\lambda)-yx=0 \\
\sim \\
\lambda ^2-(w+z)\lambda +(wz-yx)=0
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** with @egreg comment

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
\mathrm{det}\begin{bmatrix}
    w-\lambda & x\\
    y &z-\lambda
    \end{bmatrix}=0 \\
\sim \\
(w-\lambda)(z-\lambda)-yx=0 \\
\sim \\
\lambda ^2-(w+z)\lambda +(wz-yx)=0
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest `gathered` instead of `array`